# There is no overlap with watershed grid in HRU analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have to calibrate a SWAT model. I have my watershed, land-use and soil data file in projected coordinate system. The coordinate system is NAD_1983_UTM_16N. When I upload the land-cover data on HRU analysis tab, an error appears:

> There is no overlap with watershed grid.

I have looked up on other resources but could not find a solution.

Any solution?

Here is the picture of my watershed and land-use layers which are perfectly overlapping:
[image]